# Setting up a Barracuda Spam Filter

Tags: exchange-2007, spam-filter, spam

We have just purchased a Barracuda Spam Firewall 300, we have set it up but are having problems authenticating with our Exchange server (2007). I spoke to Barracuda about it and they said I need to exclude the Barracuda box from authentication from within Exchange, how do I do that?

Comment: Looking at Exchange I already created a Receive Coonector for the Spam Filter with the IP/Sub Net for that box, with Anonymous User permissions with TLS security. I think I just need to run the command, I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232021.aspx

Comment: What does the following command actually do?

Get-ReceiveConnector "Receive Connector Name" | Add-ADPermission -User "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" -ExtendedRights "Ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Recipient"

Any idea's?

Comment: "The above command gives the Anonymous Logon account permission to Ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Recipient (relaying) on the specified connector. That way, once you have allowed anonymous users to use that connector as well as grant them Ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Recipient, they will now be able to relay via the specified connector." http://www.shudnow.net/2008/02/10/client-to-server-secure-smtp-connectivity-in-exchange-server-2007/